# Notification .setContentText not displayed on Android 10

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a simple expandable notification.

Normal Layout: 
Title
**Short** Text (.setContentText)

Explanded:
Title
**Long** Text (.setStyle)

In Android 10 (API 29) this does not work anymore as only the long text is partially shown. Take a look at the litte arrows in the top right corner.

[image]

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_TEST_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
    .setContentTitle("This is the title")
    .setContentText("This is the content, which is not displayed in Android 10.")
    .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("The only displayed text in Android 10. contentText missing."))
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH) // by channel from Android 8
    .setAutoCancel(true) // Android 8

with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
    // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
    notify(101, builder.build())
}

private const val CHANNEL_TEST_ID = "TEST"
private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val name = "Test"
        val descriptionText = "Test"
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_TEST_ID, name, importance).apply {
            description = descriptionText
        }
        // Register the channel with the system
        val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

    }
}
```

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Please show screenshots of what you're seeing on each platform

Answer (score 1):

Google has confirmed this is a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141403558